# App for reading Academic PDFs

Tags: pdf, preview

My question is very simple.

I read a lot of scientific papers, full of equations, references etc... and sometimes going back and forth through all the pages is annoying.

A nice feature of TexShop is the ability to preview referenced equations by hovering over the reference (see screenshot below).

Is there an app for MacOS which allows this feature while reading PDFs? Preview is fine for my purpose, but it misses this nice feature.

Thank you!

[image: I]

Comment: @SolarMike Which question on the Academia Stack are you referring to?

Comment: this one: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/151425/72855 Sorry, perhaps it is not you but a similar issue.

Comment: @SolarMike that's not my question and probably you haven't understood the question in the OP.

Comment: That would only work if the equation/reference in the PDF was a link to another part of the document. So what you're looking for is  a PDF app that shows the contents of internal links as 'popover' windows, like QuickLook. I'm not aware of any PDF Viewer that does that.

Comment: @benwiggy I am looking exactly what you are describing. Is QuickLook an app for MacOS? Or you are referring to the quick preview one gets by pressing the Spacebar?

Comment: Yes, QuickLook is the Spacebar preview. Tell me, can you click on these references in the PDF and be taken to the page with the reference? Because if the link isn't hard-coded into the PDF, then this is just some magic that TexShop is doing with the underlying TeX data.

Comment: In Preview, you don't need to go back several pages after clicking on a link. On the menu, select Go / Back or press command-[

Answer (score 1):

You can open pdf files with TeXShop even if you don't have the corresponding TeX files.

In the Finder, control-click on the file and choose Open With / TeXShop.

In the Terminal, do `open -a TexShop foo.pdf`.

Comment: Thanks for you answer but I don't like this solution. TeXShop does not allow to set Bookmarks, highlight text etc..

Comment: @apt45: That's pretty cold... someone answers your question, and you don't even give them the courtesy of an upvote because they couldn't read your mind. I'll do that for you.

Comment: @Seamus I didn’t downvote the answer, where is the unkindness? SE works because you don’t just get an upvote for any answer your provide. I thanks lhf but if I liked TeXShop, I would have used it.

Comment: @apt45: He answered the question you asked. And I never said you downvoted - I said you didn't upvote.

Comment: @Seamus oh god, I did the example of TeXShop in the OP, so I already knew that TeXShop allowed this feature. Why would I have asked this question if I was happy with TeXShop? You don’t need to know how to read my mind to understand this.

Comment: @Seamus from my question it was clear that I am looking for something which fits the description “Preview + this nice feature”.

Comment: You said, "I don't like this solution. TeXShop does not allow to set Bookmarks, highlight text etc..". That was not in your question. If you feel you've done the right thing, then we'll drop this. In fact, we'll drop it regardless. Bye